# ActiveMQ prevent consumer handling specific message

Tags: activemq-classic

We have a design challenge where the situation is as follow:

There are multiple producers and multiple consumers (on same queue).

Each message represent a task with parameters that consumer needs to handle.

The problem is that there are certain tasks that take lots of memory (and cpu power) which we know the consumer have no capacity to handle this. the good thing is that we know how much memory (and cpu power) it approximately can take in advance, so we could prevent a consumer taking that task and giving a change to other consumer with enough memory to handle.

There is the prefetch setting but i can't see how it can configure to meet this requirement

Finally I found an option to *rollback* a transaction, so the consumer can basically check if it has enough hardware resources to handle the task and if not rollback which retrieves the message back to queue allowing next consumer take it and so forth.

Not sure if that's the right approach or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The messages could have properties set which indicate whether or not they will require high CPU and/or memory and then consumers could use selectors to only receive the messages which fit their hardware constraints.

Comment: Thanks. Which properties, can you give an example?

Comment: Most messaging APIs (e.g. JMS) support setting arbitrary properties on a message.  The names and values of these properties are completely up to you.  Using properties and selectors is typically the way applications deal with this kind of use-case.

Comment: so in case message is not fit to consumer hardware needs, how can we retrieve the message back to queue? using rollback?

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem as the amount of free memory/CPU usage for the consumer is a dynamic data which change every moment. selectors are fixes static value. i need some way to retrieve message back to queue so another consumer with enough resources can take it.

Comment: CPU and memory will certainly fluctuate to a degree over time on any given machine. However, surely there must be a baseline by which you can make a decision about if a machine can handle a job. If not, then what is to say that even though at one moment the machine can't handle the job the next moment it can?  Also, while a selector is static for the lifetime of a consumer if the environment changes sufficiently the consumer could be closed and recreated with a different selector. Lastly, if you want to send a message back to a queue then a rollback would be appropriate.